# the meaning of the verb 'care'

Tags: meaning

Here's what Jane Goodall said in a [movie trailer](https://youtu.be/3tIJpSLXAeQ) of 'War for the Planet of the Apes':

> No one anointed us ruler of this kingdom. It’s not ours to own. We are simply one of the animal species on our planet, not separate, not superior. We hold in our hands a responsibility to preserve harmony in the natural world. To demonstrate compassion towards all who call this home. So many living creatures have feelings, know loss, suffer pain. We must understand the mutual dependence between humans and animals. Only if we understand can we **care**. Only if we **care** can all be saved.

In the last two sentences, the verb 'care' has been used.
What does 'care' in this context mean?

Which does it mean?

> (1) to feel that something is important and worth worrying about
>
> (2) to like or love somebody and worry about what happens to them

(These are definitions found in [this dictionary](http://www.oxfordlearnersdictionaries.com/definition/english/care_2).)

And to ask a more general question, are these definitions mutually exclusive when enough context is provided as here?

Comment: Why would those definitions be mutually exclusive? If you love somebody, I would assume you think they are important.

Comment: Why are you omitting the third meaning that is listed? It fits your case as well: _"care to do something, to make the effort to do something"_. Also, the presence of the earlier word "**compassion**" (in your snippet) should give you a hint.

Comment: @oerkelens I didn't say anything about them being "mutually exclusive". I only asked if they are.

Comment: @Flater Because the third meaning would require the verb to be followed by "to do something", which is not present in her speech.

Comment: I'm sorry to suggest, the Question misses the point. What's important is her general meaning, not a limited precis of one dictionary's definition of a single word; not even when that's the  crucial word in the whole passage. 
It isn't necessary to understand any of what she said in order to care, and it's not just if we care, but if we take action that any can be saved.
While you clearly did ask about them being mutually exclusive they’re not at all. They're identical. 
What you meant by *given a context* isn't obvious. Did that mean *in some contexts* or what, please?

Comment: @RobbieGoodwin I've edited "given a context" to make it clear. 

Regarding your comment about taking action, I agree with you. But my question and this forum are about the language. They're not about anything else. So I think it's uncalled for to judge my question--or any question in this forum for that matter--based upon "anything else". 

I know that "her general meaning" is important, but still I wanna know the "precise meaning" of the verb 'care'. Am I somehow forbidden to be wanting to know such a meaning?

Comment: Thanks JK2 and of course you're not forbidden… that doesn't alter the fact that you clearly asked about a limited precis of one dictionary's definition.

If you wanna know the precise meaning of the verb *to care* you should first look in half a dozen dictionaries; perhaps more. If that doesn't help you should take the Question to English Language Learners or some other, more simple site.

Comment: @RobbieGoodwin I've looked at more than half a dozen dictionaries. They're basically the same in having these two distinct meanings under the verb 'care'. And please don't give me that 'Go to some other site', or 'This isn't the right site for your question' BS. I've seen much more rudimentary questions in this site than mine, without any objection thereto.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The only definitive way to know the answer would be to ask Jane Goodall herself.  But I think we can understand it from analyzing her words.

To understand the specific intended meaning of care, I think the two most important sentences are:

> To demonstrate compassion towards all who call this home.
>
> We must understand the mutual dependence between humans and animals.

Now for reference, let's pull up your two definitions.

> (1) to feel that something is important and worth worrying about
>
> (2) to like or love somebody and worry about what happens to them

Definition 2 implies a personal connection to an individual.  You love your dog, you love your mom, you love your best friend.  You cannot truly love a large group of animals you've never had any interaction with.  You can like the IDEA of them and appreciate them, but you cannot form a bond with someone/something you've never met.

Definition 1 talks about feeling that something is important and worth worrying about.  This could be a person, but it could also be a social cause, your grades, taxes, an inanimate object.  It's more open ended.

I believe **definition 1** is closer to the intended meaning.  If we are to "demonstrate compassion towards **all** who call this home" then that is a very large group of individuals.  I think arguably one could not love every single animal on the planet.  But one could certainly be generally concerned for their well-being as a group and think them worth worrying about.

I think this is reinforced by her idea that we should "understand the mutual dependence between humans and animals."  She isn't calling for us to love every animal, but to be compassionate and concerned for animals that feel much the same way we do.  This is more reflective of the general "to feel that something is important and worth worrying about" as opposed to liking or loving an individual.

But, I will also say that with words like this, you cannot necessarily separate the two definitions.  To answer your question if they are mutually exclusive, I would say no.  A word like "care" will have many definitions.  And if you experience #2, you would certainly experience #1.  But you could experience #1 without loving a particular individual. Another dictionary would also provide a very different definition that could easily combine those two.  There is no simple, definitive definition for a word like "care."

Comment: Perhaps the best answer I think I've gotten in years. Kudos to you for giving me this beautiful answer. By the way, if you could find such a dictionary that combines the two definitions, please let me know.